# Extract data from XML using T-SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a SQL Server table with the following columns

```
 ID, Attributes
```

`Attributes` data is in XML format and there are multiple values in it. I want to extract a particular value from that column. I tried the below query. But it is giving error. Could someone please help

```
SELECT 
    ID,
    CAST (identityiq.spt_link.attributes AS XML).value('Attributes/Map/entry[@key="c"]/@value','nvarchar(200)') 
FROM
    identityiq.spt_link 
WHERE 
    id = '8aae1d856c57c7bd016c5a0e16d00267'
```

XML data inside `Attributes` column

```
<Attributes>
  <Map>
    <entry key="Privileged"/>
    <entry key="Service"/>
    <entry key="c" value="US"/>   
  </Map>
</Attributes>
```

Error

> Msg 2389, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
>   XQuery [value()]: 'value()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type 'xdt:untypedAtomic *'

Comment: Please include the full error message you get. Also, XML elements and attributes are case-sensitive, i.e. `attributes` will not match `<Attributes>`.

Answer (score 2):

Your XML could be as follows in which case the Xpath matches more than one node

```
<Attributes>
  <Map>
    <entry key="c" value="Foo"/>   
    <entry key="c" value="Bar"/>  
  </Map>
</Attributes>
```

you need to use

```
.value('(Attributes/Map/entry[@key="c"])[1]/@value','nvarchar(200)')
```

So it is defined that you want the first matching node and you meet the requirement that the expression return a singleton (or empty sequence)

Answer (score 0):

Create a xml variable eg. Declare @attribute xml and set xml value in this variable

```
Select [TABLE].[Column].value('(entry[@key="c"])[2]/@value','varchar(200)'),[TABLE].[Column].value('(entry[@key="c"])[1]/@value','varchar(200)') from @attribute.nodes('/Attributes/Map') AS [TABLE] ([Column])
```